# What do they mean by “most single-gene traits are recessive.” How can a gene be recessive; isn’t it an allele which can be recessive or dominant?

Tags: genetics

Here’s the paragraph pg. 45 of “Principle of Neural Science”: “Although most single-gene traits are recessive, rearrangements that lead to duplication or deletion of multiple genes often have dominant effects. For example, individuals with three copies of chromosome 21 have Down syndrome due to the increased expression of multiple genes; no single gene when present in three copies is known to cause the cognitive and physical manifestations of Down syndrome.“
In addition to the question above, when they refer to the dominant effect of multiple genes, what do they exactly mean?

Answer (score 1):

Yah, that is kind of sloppy.  I guess what they mean is that single gene traits usually follow the classic Mendelian pattern.  (Though I wouldn't be surprised if that wasn't true, if incomplete or co-dominance were more common)

I'd say that having extra copies doesn't really follow the Mendelian pattern at all, so it's weird to say its "dominant".

I'm guessing that this book only barely touches on genetics.  Honestly, it strikes me as kind of juvenile to take Medelian genetics as the touchstone of genetics, and try to squash everything into that paradigm.  Perhaps that made sense historically, when Mendelian genetics was the first attempt to really understand inheritance, but with what we know now, it makes more sense to think the the Mendelian paradigm as something that applies only sometimes; easier to realize that it just isn't particular relevant when taking about, say, gene dosage.